# Iris GO: Get form urlencoded data not working

Tags: go, slack

I'm trying with something very simple, get the information from a slack command of an app I'm building, and since I'm very new with Go I found that Iris is a very good framework so I decided to use it and the example from the website it's actually working https://iris-go.com/v10/recipe#Read Form90 but when I receive data from slack, is not and this error always appear.

```
➜  slack-app go run iris.go
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 POST: /prices -> main.main.func1() and 2 more
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 Application: running using 1 host(s)
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 Host: addr is :8080
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 Host: virtual host is localhost:8080
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 Host: register startup notifier
[DBUG] 2018/01/19 22:10 Host: register server shutdown on interrupt(CTRL+C/CMD+C)
Now listening on: http://localhost:8080
Application started. Press CMD+C to shut down.
[WARN] 2018/01/19 22:10 Recovered from a route's Handler('main.main.func1')
At Request: 200 /prices POST ::1
Trace: reflect.Value.Interface: cannot return value obtained from unexported field or method

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:509
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491
/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:942
/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:931
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/utils.go:18
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/binder.go:371
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/binder.go:361
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/binder.go:271
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/binder.go:165
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/vendor/github.com/iris-contrib/formBinder/binder.go:153
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:1972
/Users/myuser/go/src/slack-app/iris.go:32
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:900
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:1172
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger/logger.go:50
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger/logger.go:31
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:900
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:1172
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover/recover.go:56
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:913
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/context/context.go:1070
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/handler.go:219
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/router.go:70
/Users/myuser/go/src/github.com/kataras/iris/core/router/router.go:147
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2619
/usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1801
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
```

**code**

```
    package main

import (
  "github.com/kataras/iris"

  "github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/logger"
  "github.com/kataras/iris/middleware/recover"
)

type Student struct {
  channel_id string
  channel_name string
  command string
  response_url string
  team_domain string
  team_id string
  text string
  token string
  trigger_id string
  user_id string
  user_name string
}

func main() {
  app := iris.New()
  app.Logger().SetLevel("debug")
  app.Use(recover.New())
  app.Use(logger.New())

  app.Post("/prices", func(ctx iris.Context) {
    student := Student{}
    err := ctx.ReadForm(&student)
    if err != nil {
      ctx.StatusCode(iris.StatusInternalServerError)
      ctx.WriteString(err.Error())
    }

    ctx.Writef("Student: %#v", student)
  })

  app.Run(iris.Addr(":8080"))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in [the documentation](https://iris-go.com/v10/recipe#Read%20Form90) you linked to suggests to use *tag/annotation* to map field to form key, and to keep your field name as needed i.e follows Go naming convention and exported :

```
type Student struct {
    ChannelID string `form:"channel_id"`
    ChannelName string `form:"channel_name"`
    ...
}
```

Field tag is common in Go and it is also used in some places within standard Go package, such us, [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json) and [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml) for serialization/deserialization of JSON and XML data, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also a newbie at Go, but the error seems to be indicating that it's trying to read an unexported field - and I see that your `Student` struct has all UNexported fields (Go treats Capitalized fields as exported and uncapitalized fields as the opposite)

Comment: But the fields from slack are coming in that way, do you know if there is function or similar to parse those underscore variables and use the Capitalized ones?